# What's the fastest approach to merging a small number of large, already sorted lists in Hadoop?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I've got a small Hadoop (CDH5.1.0, MRv2/YARN) cluster (5x nodes 4CPU, 16GB RAM, 600GB disk) of which contains a small number ~30 of ~15GB SequenceFiles. The SequenceFiles contains pairs of `BytesWritable`/`BytesWritable`, and the keys are not uniformly distributed across the possible keyspace - it's rather lumpy. However, these files are sorted.

I need to merge these together to create a single, sorted SequenceFile, as efficiently as possible. I've tried a number of approaches already, but haven't been very successful.

Initially, I tried using a MapReduce job with a RandomSampler and TotalOrderPartitioner, and around 1000 Reducers. However, it turns out that because of the non-uniformity of the input keys, the RandomSampler isn't very good at distributing the data across the partitions, and I end up with 999 reducers succeeding, and 1 failing due to running out of local disk.

It occurs to me that this approach doesn't appear to take advantage of the fact that the input data is already sorted - it would solve the problem if my input data were in a Random order.

I notice that there's a SequenceFile.Sorter class that aims to simply merge SequenceFiles together into a single sorted output. While this would be a single-threaded process, would this be better than the MR approach? Is there a different MR approach I could take that could exploit the fact that my input data is already sorted? It would seem that the fastest way to do this would be to do a simple merge, but is there a way I could do this in parallel across the cluster?